# Custom lighting switches

Tags: lighting

I need a double (over/under) three way switch, preferrably rocker switch where both swiches have pilot lights.  Any manufacturer is fine.

Comment: I don't see any 3-way switches with locator lights.  Probably because not all wiring configurations guarantee a neutral will be available in the box.  Would you consider glow-in-the-dark switches or an always-on nightlight nearby?

Answer (score 0):

[single-gang duplex combo, 3-way/3-way rocker- no pilot light](http://www.leviton.com/OA_HTML/ProductDetail.jsp?partnumber=5643-W&section=41436&minisite=10251)

NOTE: common terminology is- a "lighted" switch glows when the switch is **off**. A "pilot light" is an indicator that a switch is **on**.